# Running bash script, results from zsh different than bash, even though script has bash shebanged

Tags: bash, zsh

I have the following script, `test.sh`, that if I call it from bash, works, but if I call it from `zsh`, doesn't, even though it has a bash shebang at the top

If I call it from zsh, I get the following error. Anyone know why?

```
$ . scripts/test.sh
scripts/test.sh:14: = not found
```

The line it's complaining about is:

```
if [ "$SOURCED" == "0" ]
```

#### test.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
(return 0 2>/dev/null) && SOURCED=1 || SOURCED=0

function showHelp(){
  local ME;
  ME=$(basename "$0")
  echo
  echo "This command needs to be run like so:"
  echo "$ . $ME "
  echo
}

# exit if not sourced or called from another script
if [ "$SOURCED" == "0" ]
then
  if [ -z "$1" ]
  then
    showHelp
    exit;
  fi
fi
```

Comment: `.` does not run a script using `bash`. It executes the contents of the file in the current shell, whether that shell is `bash`, `zsh`, or some other POSIX-like shell.

Comment: `.` does not "execute" the script, it "sources" the script.  If you want to execute the script, run `./scripts/test.sh` or just `scripts/test.sh`

Comment: Yeah my script is more complex, and it was working, even when I source it from zsh, but then I cleaned up my `.zshrc` to make it faster and it started happening - I couldn't see it, but maybe some plugin I was sourcing was setting some bash compatibility mode or something? Regardless this fixes it. Thanks!

Comment: @BradParks : You can't source a bash script from Zsh. This would be like doing a `#include` inside a C program, where the included file is Java.

Comment: Yeah I get the idea - my bad! I guess I thought sourcing didn't just include the file, I thought it ran it, then took the output of that and merged it with the target environment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.` does not mean "run this file with `bash`". It means execute the contents in the *current* shell.

Further, the `[` built-in in `zsh`, unlike the one in `bash`, does not accept `==` as a string comparision operator. You have to use `=`. (As an aside, you should use `[ ... = ... ]` in `bash` as well, to avoid confusion.) If you want to use `==`, use `[[ "$SOURCED" == "0" ]]` instead.

The shebang is only used if you execute the script as the command itself, for example `./test.sh` or `/some/absolute/path/to/test.sh` or `test.sh` (if `test.sh` is in a directory on your `PATH`).

For whatever historical reason, `.` was chosen for the command name, despite the potential for confusion with `.` as the name of the current directory (`. test.sh` vs `./test.sh` vs `. ./test.sh`). Though POSIX does not require a more readable synonym, most modern shells provide `source` as an (near) equivalent. (Because it is not standard, though, the behavior of `source` can vary from shell to shell. I believe `.` and `source` are equivalent in `bash`, but there is a slight difference regarding `PATH` lookup of its argument between the two in `zsh`.)

Comment: ahh.... i should've realized that (esp the "sourcing runs it in the current shell, and ignores the shebang")... thanks!